# form values are not saved in modal

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

I am quite new in php coding and I am taking back the developpement of a website from another developer who left. 
I am using symfony 2.
My page is a list of meetings on a particular subject. That works fine.
I have added the possibility to add an expert for particulat meetings. That works fine as well.
What I wanted to add is a modal to be able to add an expert on the subject without changing page. I have then created a AddExpert page which works fine if called alone. When I click on the button, it register correctly the expert in the db and I can then use it. However, when clicking on the button in the modal, the modal disappear but the expert is not created.

Here is my code:
Where I have the button to popup the modal with the list of expert:

```
<td>
        {{ form_widget(meeting.expert, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </td>
    <td>

        <a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" href="{{  path("appli_addexpert") }}" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>

    </td>
```

The tag mymodal is the following but it overwritten with my addExpert page:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my simple addExpert.html.twig page which works fine on his own:

```
    {% block body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Add a new expert</h3>
            <form method="post">
                {{ form_widget(form_create) }}
                <button id="button-id-modal" type="submit">Add Expert</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have read some webpages saying that ajax might be required for it to work. Unfortunately I am not an expert yet so I need some help there. I have tried to add the following javascript part in my block javascript either in the page with all the meetings or in the addExpert/html.twig page but it does not work either:

```
function postForm($form, callback){
            var values = {};
            console.log($form.serializeArray());
            $.each( $form.serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
                values[field.name] = field.value;
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data : values,
                success: callback || function (data) {
                    console.log('Saved!')
                }
            });
        }

        window.postForm = postForm;
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT:

In my controller I have the following:

```
/**
 * @Route("/expert/add")
 * @Template()
 */
public function addExpertAction(Request $request)
{
    $expert      = new Expert();
    $form_create = $this->createForm(new ExpertType, $expert);
    $form_create->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form_create->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($expert);
        $em->flush();
        $this->get("session")->getFlashBag()->add(
            "success",
            "Expert " . $expert->getName() . " successfully added !"
        );

       return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('bdl_appli_manage_expertlist'));
    }

    return array(
        "form_create" => $form_create->createView(),
    );

}
```

I am guessing the return should be changed then but not sure how as it should only close the modal

Answer (score 0):

First of all i dont see where you call “postForm”
This function should get a jquery form element and a call back that will be called wheb the ajax call is back.
The second thing is the “url” ib the ajax call it’s looks like you are depending on “action” attribute in the form that should contain the endpoint url, but you have no this attribute in your form element.

Comment: I have added the addExpertAction from my controller. However I am not sure how to modify the redirect then.

Comment: also I have the form method = "post" in my addExpert.html.twig. So it should be taken there right?

Comment: hi, I have added in my addExpert.html.twig an action: action="{{ path('appli_addexpert') }}" I just now need to send the correct URL back in my addExpertAction from my controler so that it goes back to the page I was looking at! Not sure how to do that... Would you have an idea?